# não ta funcionando modal e o java script e uma função

Tags: php, javascript, modal

fiz um crud que cadastra e exclui e edita, só que na parte de editar não funciona  o modal tambem parte do codigo que eu acho q ta os problemas:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="load_modal('<?php echo $value->titulo;?>', '<?php echo $value->categoria; ?>','<?php echo $value->autor; ?>','<?php echo $value->breve_resumo; ?>', '<?php echo $value->id; ?>')">
                Editar
          </button>//esse é  do botão editar ele aparece só que não ta fazendo a função de editar e nem aparecendo o modal
```

aqui é o codigo do modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labellebby="myModalLabel">
           <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dimissmiss="modal" aria-label="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times</span></button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Alterando Livros</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-inline" method="POST">

                   <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">titulo:</span>
                     <input id="text_titulo" name="titulo" type="text" class="form-control" required value="">
                   </div>

                   <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">categoria:</span>
                     <input id="text_categoria" name="categoria" type="text" class="form-control" required value="">
                   </div>

                   <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">autor:</span>
                     <input id="text_autor" name="autor" type="text" class="form-control" required value="">
                   </div>
                   <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">breve resumo:</span>
                     <input id="text_breve_resumo" name="breve_resumo" type="text" class="form-control" required value="">
                   </div>

                   <input  id="id_uii" name="id_ui" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>"/>
                   <input  name="alterar" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Alterar">
                       </form>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
```

Comment: Consegue elaborar um [mcve] demonstrando o problema? Aproveita para descrever o que seria o "não funciona".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, ta faltando exemplificar mais o problema, mas dando uma analisada eu vejo que está usando Bootstrap.

Para ver se esta tudo certo no seu modal , coloca esse jquery dentro de uma função e chame-a -->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
});
```

se isso não funcionar, é bom saber se outros componentes do bootstrap estão rodando, para descartar a possibilidade de erro na importação dos styles.

Comment: no modal-action tem que colocar oque nele?

Comment: amigo eu coloquei o codigo não abriu o modal só aparaceu um link escrito o "vai abrir o modal" encima na pagina

Comment: coloquei e agora ?

Comment: não é Materialize amigo..... coloca esse Jquery dentro de uma função e chame - a...       $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
});

Comment: tipo eu coloquei so que a aparece o link ecrito 'vai abrir modal' so que quando clikco no 'vai abrir modal' aparece na URL #myModal

Comment: MANDA A PAGINA INTEIRA NO MEU EMAIL, EU VEJO PRA VOCÊ. jony.nunes@fatec.sp.gov.br.

Comment: amigo eu consegui  roda o modal, é que eu tinha escrito uma parte errado no script k

Comment: kkkk, que bom amigo, isso faz parte da rotina

Comment: agora estou com outro problema, abre o modal para editar so que quando eu clico no botão editar da esse seguinte  erro : Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'titulo' cannot be null in /home/lgobira/projetos/Painellivro_clig/classes/livro2.php:49 Stack trace: #0 /home/lgobira/projetos/Painellivro_clig/classes/livro2.php(49): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /home/lgobira/projetos/Painellivro_clig/index.php(100): Livro2->update('352') #2 {main} thrown in /home/lgobira/projetos/Painellivro_clig/classes/livro2.php on line 49

Comment: Me parece que está enviando um valor nulo para a coluna título, pelo jeito tem restrição not null no banco.... dica... espalhe console log pelo seu código

Comment: Amigo, retire o status de [Pendente], e se quiser pode dar um voto positivo na minha resposta. xp

Comment: ta td bem kk, mas me ajuda aqui com esse problema esse problema no banco não entendo muito estou começando agora no mundo dos codigos

Comment: como tiro  o status de [pendente] ?